# How to match anything in a regular expression up to a character and not including it?

Tags: python, regex

For example if I have a string `abc%12341%%c%9876` I would like to substitute from the last % in the string to the end with an empty string, the final output that I'm trying to get is `abc%12341%%c`.

I created a regular expression `'.*#'` to search for the last % meaning abc%12341%%c% , and then getting the index of the the last % and then just replacing it with an empty string.

I was wondering if it can be done in one line using re.sub(..)

Comment: You do not need a regex for this, use `'abc%12341%%c%9876'.rpartition('%')[0]`, see [demo](https://ideone.com/hhOqMj).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern, and then replace with empty string:

```
%[^%]*$
```

Sample script:

```py
inp = "abc%12341%%c%9876"
output = re.sub(r'%[^%]*$', '', inp)
print(output)  # abc%12341%%c
```

The regex pattern says to match the final `%` sign, followed by zero or more non `%` characters, up to the end of the string.  We then replace with empty string, to effectively remove this content from the input.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is called lookahead matching - I will look it up if I am not too slow :-)

(?=...)
Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'